# Javascript 'in' function showing weird behavior

Tags: javascript

I was just testing the `in` operator in Javascript. When I run something like `console.log("cookie" in document)`, it logs `true`, but when I do `console.log("cookie" in "cookiejar")` or assign **cookiejar** to a variable `a` and then do `console.log("cookie" in a)`, I get an error statement **TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a**. Can anyone tell me why is it behaving like this?

Comment: Yes, the docs can: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: Probably because there are no cookies in the jar, or the entire cookiejar does'nt exist, at least not the string representation of it, and it does'nt check for strings in strings but keys in objects.

Comment: use the jquery "in operator" plugin. it works more better.

Comment: You can do `"a" in new String("b")` (returns false)

Comment: Hi Matt, I tried `console.log("cookie" in new String(a));`, for `a = 'cookiejar', still it is returning `false`...

Comment: @Cupidvogel because `"cookie"` is not a property of `"cookiejar"`. It's merely a substring.

Comment: @Cupidvogel on the other hand, `"toString" in new String("")` returns `true`.

Comment: But the Mozilla link contains similar examples..

Comment: @Cupidvogel No, it doesn't. Are you referring to `var color1 = new String("green"); "length" in color1; // returns true`? The string `length` isn't a substring of the string `green`, but the String object does have the property `length`.

Comment: O ho, I get it. So the operator checks whether the quoted sting on the left exists as a property of the object on the right. Right?

Comment: But if I fill an array with some stuff and do `for (x in a) { console.log(x); }`, I get the list of indices from 0 to length-1. Which property is that, then?

Comment: @Cupidvogel the indices to an array are its properties. `length` is its property as well, but it's not `enumerable` so it doesn't appear in `for ... in`

Comment: Also, `in` in `for`/`in` is different than the `in` operator.

Comment: @Cupidvogel `for..in` and `in` are totally different. `for..in` loops over the enumerable properties of an object; `in` returns a boolean.

Comment: So is that what you call operator overloading, having different functionalities in different contexts?

Comment: @Cupidvogel the `in` keyword in `for .. in` is not an operator.

Comment: Is there any property which determines whether another property of the same object is enumerable?

Comment: @Cupidvogel normally (in ES3), you can't create non-`enumerable` properties.

Comment: @Cupidvogel yes: `obj.propertyIsEnumerable("propertyName")`

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Just another question, if an object has more than one set of enunerable properties, which ones will the above loop log?

Comment: A `for-in` loop enumerates all enumerable properties of the object itself and those in its prototype chain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator doesn't do what you think it does.  *a* `in` *b* tells you if a given object *b* has the property named *a*.

You cannot use `in` to search for characters in a string.  Use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) for that.

```
'cookiejar'.indexOf('cookie')
```

---

Note that the `in` [*operator*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.7) is entirely separate from and completely unrelated to the [`for-in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) [*statement*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4).

Answer (score 4):

`in` only applies to objects, not strings.

[From the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.7):

5 If Type(rval) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.

Comment: Is there any benefit (practical use-case) of `a in b` over `typeOf b[a] !== "undefined"`?

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes -- properties that have been reset to `undefined`, but still exist on the object: "*If you set a property to `undefined` but do not `delete` it, the in operator returns `true` for that property.*"

Comment: @JanDvorak: `a in b` is certainly much shorter.  Additionally, a property can exist on an object independent of whether its value is defined.

Comment: @apsillers i'm wondering under which circumstances is this the desired piece of information.

Comment: @JanDvorak any situation in which `undefined` is a valid value. While rare, it's possible... e.g. in meta-programming type stuff where the property represents the value that a variable holds, while the property's absence represents a variable not existing.